# It appears that the code does not produce a text file even though no error is displayed

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter

The code is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
  class M_change
  {
     static string M_time_pick(string[][] arr) 
     {
        Time_pick_3 T3 = new Time_pick_3();
        decimal[][] output_time_pick_3 = T3.M();

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("M_change");

        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < 14; a++)
            {
                sw.Write(" " + arr[i][a]);
            }
            sw.WriteLine();
        }

        sw.Close();
        return "M_change";
     }
  }
}
```

I can't find the `.txt` file nor an error, the code compiles fine. It must be said that it is a code with many items and this is one of them. 
I did look in the Debug folder and the Release folder, but no file was made...

Comment: The `.txt` file will be created in the directory where the app runs - if you runs this from within Visual Studio, that's typically `(project-dir)\bin\debug` ....

Comment: When you call StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(); you must pass the path where the file will be created. Right now you are only passing the file name, thus it will be created inside the bin\Debug or bin\Release folder (depending on which one you are working). Change that line to StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\M_change"); instead and you'll see that the file is visible in your C:\ Directory

Comment: These answers are correct. I just wanted to add that you should consider wrapping your `StreamWriter` in a `using` block. Doing that will remove the need to call the `Close()` method and will ensure proper disposal.

Comment: Do you call the `M_time_pick` method? If so then please show the code where you do.

Comment: Also, you don't name the file with a `.txt` extension, the file will be placed in whatever is the "current directory" for your application and named `M_change` without an extension. Are you sure you're looking for the right file in the right place?

Answer (score 1):

The file will be in your bin/Debug directory in your solution:

```
C:\Users\auser\Documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\StreamwriterExample\StreamwriterExample\bin\Debug
```

Comment: It is not in that folder, I tried on two separate computers .

Answer (score 0):

There is no `.txt` file, it is simply named `M_change` without any extension.

Do you call that function from `static Main()`? At least make sure that it gets called at all.

Comment: Yes I called it in the main, using: 
M_change ME = new M_change            
string output_M_change = ME.M_time_pick ();